# Errors in display and broadcasting for a basic structure

Tags: julia

I have two problems with defining a composite type.

I'm following the interfaces section of the manual in Julia v0.6. I've built a simple Minimum (non)Working Example:

```
mutable struct Group <: AbstractArray{Integer, 1}
    x1::Int64
    x2::Int64
end

Base.size(g::Group) = 2
Base.length(g::Group) = 2
Base.eltype(::Type{Group}) = Int64
Base.getindex(g::Group, i::Int64) = getindex([g.x1, g.x2], i)
Base.setindex!(g::Group, v, i::Int64) = Base.setindex!(g, v, i)
Base.IndexStyle(::Type{<:Group}) = IndexLinear()

Base.start(g::Group) = 1
Base.next(g::Group, s::Int) = g[s], s+1
Base.done(g::Group, s::Int) = (s > length(g))

Base.show(io::IO, g::Group) = print("\t", string(g.x1), "\n\t", string(g.x2))
```

It's promising:

```
julia> g = Group(1, 2);
julia> g.x1 = 42
42 
julia> g.x1 = 99
99
julia> length(g)
2
julia> for i in h
       @show i
      end
i = 99
i = 2
```

But:

```
g = Group(1, 2)
```

This gives the error (in Juno):

```
Error displaying Group: MethodError: no method matching inds2string(::Base.OneTo{Int64})[0m
Closest candidates are:
  inds2string([91m::Tuple{Vararg{AbstractUnitRange,N}} where N[39m) at show.jl:1568
_summary(::Group, ::Base.OneTo{Int64}) at show.jl:1573
#showarray#265(::Bool, ::Function, ::IOContext{Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}}, ::Group, ::Bool) at show.jl:1685
(::Atom.##17#18{Group})(::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}) at display.jl:17
#sprint#230(::Void, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Function) at io.jl:66
Type at types.jl:39 [inlined]
Type at types.jl:40 [inlined]
render(::Juno.Editor, ::Group) at display.jl:19
render′(::Juno.Editor, ::Group) at errors.jl:105
(::Atom.##103#108{String})() at eval.jl:91
macro expansion at eval.jl:87 [inlined]
(::Atom.##100#105{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:80
```

but:

```
help?> inds2string
search:

Couldn't find inds2string
Perhaps you meant randstring
  No documentation found.

  Binding inds2string does not exist.
```

The second problem is because I'd like to use broadcasting:

```
julia> sin.(g)
```

then I get this error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Base.OneTo{Int64} to an
object of type CartesianRange
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor CartesianRange(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
CartesianRange(::Base.OneTo{Int64}) at sysimg.jl:77
broadcast_c at broadcast.jl:314 [inlined]
broadcast(::Function, ::Group) at broadcast.jl:455
include_string(::String, ::String) at loading.jl:522
include_string(::String, ::String, ::Int64) at eval.jl:30
include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N}
where N) at eval.jl:34
(::Atom.##102#107{String,Int64,String})() at eval.jl:82
withpath(::Atom.##102#107{String,Int64,String}, ::Void) at utils.jl:30
withpath(::Function, ::String) at eval.jl:38
hideprompt(::Atom.##101#106{String,Int64,String}) at repl.jl:67
macro expansion at eval.jl:80 [inlined]
(::Atom.##100#105{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:80
```

which is not very helpful. I obviously need to add something else to the definition for `Group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `size` method returns an integer; `size` should return a tuple of integers with the lengths in each dimension. In this case, when we define a vector, it should return a 1-tuple, something like:

```
Base.size(::Group) = (2, )
```

Unfortunately this lead to the somewhat obscure error messages downstream.

---

Some other comments that might be helpful:

Your getindex works, but allocates an unnecessary `Vector`, perhaps something like the following would be better:

```
function Base.getindex(g::Group, i::Int)
    if i == 1
        return g.x1
    elseif i == 2
        return g.x2
    else
        throw(BoundsError(g, i))
    end
end
```

Your definition of `setindex!` calls itself and would lead to a `StackOverflow` error, perhaps something like the following would be better:

```
function Base.setindex!(g::Group, v, i)
    println("setindex!(:Group, v = $v, i = $i)")
    if i == 1
        g.x1 = v
    elseif i == 2
        g.x2 = v
    else
        throw(BoundsError(g, i))
    end
end
```